# Please explain this expression

Tags: c++, qt, templates, smart-pointers, qsharedpointer

```
class TestPtr : protected QSharedPointer<Test>
```

where `Test` is an abstract interface class.
The `TestPtr` class should serve as the smart pointer class.

Does this mean class `TestPtr` is derived from the class `Test` ? Is class test enclosed in a smart pointer?
 I read that `QSharedPointer` is a template class. Could somebody please clarify?

Comment: *"I read that QSharedpointer is a template class."* - that, erm, is [the answer to your question](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/).

Comment: This means that TestPtr is derived from QSharedPointer<Test> in a protected way, what's the problem with that? do you know what does template class mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What it doesn't mean**

1. That `TestPtr` derives from `Test` -- it does not.
2. That `class Test` is enclosed in a smart pointer (but close: it means that *instances of*  `TestPtr` will actually be smart pointers to `Test` without letting the world know about it except as the author of `TestPtr` explicitly chooses to)

**What it means**

It means that `TestPtr` wants to implement the functionality of a smart pointer to `Test` (which is what `QSharedPointer<Test>` is -- please note I have no idea exactly what `QSharedPointer` does, I 'm just "reading what's in the name").

To achieve this, the author of `TestPtr` plans to extensively use the functionality built into the inner works of `QSharedPointer` (that's why `TestPtr` inherits instead of having a `QSharedPointer` member -- to be able to use the `protected` members of `QSharedPointer`).

However, the author plans for `TestPtr` to **not** be equivalent to a `QSharedPointer<TestPtr>` even if the class has about the same functionality (we don't know the reason for this with the given information). That's why the inheritance is not `public`.

Answer (score 3):

`TestPtr` is derived from the particular version of the template class `QSharedPointer` which has been instantiated with the class `Test` as its template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean class TestPtr is derived from the class Test ?

No. `TestPtr` is derived from `QSharedPointer`.

> Is class test enclosed in a smart pointer?

Yes. Rather, `QSharedPointer<Test>` is a smart pointer class that manages `Test` pointers.

> I read that QSharedpointer is a template class. Could somebody please clarify?

Templates abstract out types similar to how functions abstract values out of operations. For example,

```
int i,j; 
...
i = 2*i+1;
j = 2*j+1;
```

can be abstracted to:

```
void foo(int &x) {
    x = 2*x + i;
}

...
int i,j,
...
foo(i);
foo(j);
```

Similarly, rather than having separate classes such as:

```
class IntSharedPtr { typedef int value_type; ... };
class FloatSharedPtr { typedef float value_type; ...};
```

You can have a template class:

```
template <typename _T>
class SharedPtr { typedef _T value_type; ...};

typedef SharedPtr<int> IntSharedPtr;
typedef SharedPtr<float> FloatSharedPtr;
```

Finally, the `protected` means that members of `QSharedPointer` are only accessible in a `TestPtr` by `TestPtr` and its descendents. Suppose `TestPtr` doesn't override `operator *` and has a constructor that takes a `Test` (or reference to a `Test`). Then the following would fail, due to access restrictions:

```
int main() {
    Test bar;
    TestPtr pbar(bar);

    *pbar; // Error: QSharedPointer<Test>::operator *() is protected within this context.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

QSharedPointer is a template class, and Test is what it templates.

TestPtr inherits from QSharedPointer (not Test - unless QSharedPointer inherits from Test - not enough info in the question to answer this, but its possible).

From the name it sounds like QSharedpointer is a smart pointer, but I am not familiar with this class to be able to answer.

In terms of protected inheritence, you might want to look at the following

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

No, class TestPtr is NOT derived from class Test. Class TestPtr does derive from

> `class QSharedPointer<Test>`

which is really class QSharedPointer, expressed in terms of class Test.

Class QSharedPointer is a template class, which means a class that is written once but can then be used for Test, or other classes.

For example, similar to class QSharedPointer, you could have a class like this:

```
template <class T>
  class Vector
    {
    };
```

You could then have instances of this vector class which stores vectors of different things. For example `Vector<int>` is one class which stores ints, and `Vector<bool>` is a different class which stores booleans.